# Возникает ошибка в событии кнопки ( Expression statement is not assignment or call )

Tags: javascript, php

Всем доброго времени суток, Я новичок в php, столкнулся с такой проблемой, пытаюсь реализовать комментирование на сайте и событие onclick кнопки не отвечает, пишет `'Expression statement is not assignment or call'` ( хотя если вне сессии все четко работает, редактирование коммента, ответ на комментарий ) пытаюсь понять может когда заносим Js функции в Session надо по другому заносить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Php file:

```php
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['all-good'])) {

        
        echo '<p id="comment-text">'.$result['name'].' '.$result['date'].'<br></p>',
        '<div id="comment-user">',
            '<p id="stealth-<'.$result['id'].'">'.$result['comment'].'</p>',
        '</div>',
        '<form method="post" action="./check%20info/editsavechanges.php">',
            '<textarea id="edit-save-<'.$result['comment'] .'>" name="id-each" hidden><'.$result['id'].'></textarea>',
            '<textarea name="edit-comment"  id="editosa-<'.$result['id'] .'>" class="edit-style" hidden ><'.$result['comment'].'></textarea>',
            '<button type="submit"  name="save-edit-comment"  id="save-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Save</button>',
            '<button type="button" onclick="cancelEdit(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="cancel-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Cancel</button>',
            '<div id="buttons-forms">',
                '<button type="button" onclick="showForm(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="open-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Edit</button>',
                '<button type="submit"  name="delete-edit-comment" id="delete-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Delete</button>',
                '<button type="button"  onclick="showReply(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" >Reply</button>',
            '</div>',

        '<textarea name="edit-comment-reply"  id="reply-text-<'.$result['id'].'>" class="edit-style-reply" hidden ></textarea>',
        '<button type="submit" name="save-reply-comment"  id="save-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Save</button>',

        '<button type="button" onclick="cancelReply(<'.$result['id'].'>)" id="cancel-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Cancel</button>',
        '<button type="submit"  id="delete-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Delete</button>',
        '<button type="submit"  id="response-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Reply</button>',
        '</form>';


       }else{
        echo '<p id="comment-text">'.$result['name'].' '.$result['date'].'<br></p>',
        '<div id="comment-user">',
            '<p id="stealth-<'.$result['id'] .'>">'.$result['comment'].'</p>',
        '</div>';
    }

?>
```

Js file:

```js
function showForm(id) {
    document.getElementById('open-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('delete-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('reply-editos-' + id).hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('stealth-' + id).hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('editosa-' + id).hidden = false;
    document.getElementById('save-editos-' + id).hidden = false;
    document.getElementById('cancel-editos-' + id).hidden = false;
}
```

Comment: может он еще и в какой строке пишет

Comment: Это сообщение ( Expression statement is not assignment or call ) отображается на строках где присутствует событие onclick то есть для showFrom, showReply, cancelEdit, cancelRepl. Решил еще проверить что в консоле показывает и  там показало при нажатии ( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `'<button type="submit"  id="delete-reply-editos-<'.$result['id'] .'>" hidden>Delete</button>',` знаки `<` и `>` являются  частью строки (они там не нужны).

После склейки получается `<button type="submit"  id="delete-reply-editos-<666>" hidden>Delete</button>`.

Comment: Интересное замечание, я сделал изменения но все так же есть проблемы с отображением.

Comment: Oбновите код в вопросе

Comment: Доброго дня, хотел сказать спасибо большое, все заработало!! оказываеться что я не так понял ( все таки еще на пути изучение много чего ) надо было  < > эти скобки убрать в каждом теге где они были присутствовали и файл <script></script> перенести в <head> а он у меня был в в сессии. Хорошего дня !

Comment: Всегда рад. Если помогло -- принимайте ответ галочкой